# CSS class selector 'container' not found Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap, clase

Estoy usando bootstrap en mi proyecto angular y tengo un problema ya que no se encuentran las clases CSS relacionadas con bootstrap.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

angular.json

```
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
```

Comment: Veo que usas Visual Studio Code. Consulta: ¿Tienes habilitada en ese editor, una extensión llamada HTML CSS Support?

Comment: Hola Cris, si, todos mis proyectos los he realizado en este editor aunque en Angular si soy nuevo, si tengo instalada la extensión y en otro foro lo solucionaban reinstalándola o regresándola algunas versiones pero no funcionó para mi. Tambien me recomendaban tener IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML y Angular Language Service pero nada.

Comment: Héctor, dos preguntas: ¿Qué versión de esa extensión tienes instalada? ¿Y con qué versiones anteriores probaste?